# Fallo en el scrip shell

Tags: linux, shell

Buenas tardes estoy aprendiendo a programar en Shell linux y me pidieron que cree un programa que me permita saber la edad de una persona mediante el ingreso de su año, mes y dia de nacimiento al igual que me imprima cuantos años tiene la persona con los meses y dias cumplidos este es mi fragmento de codigo, el error esque al ingresar un mes despues del que estamos o el mes en el que estamos me ejecuta mal los meses y dias ayuda porfavor.

```
echo "Ingrese su año de nacimiento"
read a
echo "Ingrese su mes de nacimiento"
read m
echo "Ingrese su dia de nacimiento"
read d

anio=$(date +%Y)
mes=$(date +%m)
dia=$(date +%d)

day=$(expr $dia - $d)
year=$(expr $anio - $a)
month=$(expr $mes - $m)

MES=$(expr $month + 12)

if [ $m -gt $mes ]
then echo "Tiene $year años"
echo "Con $MES meses"
echo "Con $day dias"
else
echo "Tiene $year años"
echo "Con $month meses"
echo "Con $day dias"
fi
```

Comment: define "me ejecute mal los meses". Proporciona un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte. También te sería de ayuda pegar el código en https://www.shellcheck.net para ver una serie de errores básicos que tiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ver si te sirve

```
#pedimos los datos por teclado
echo "Ingrese su año de nacimiento"
#let a_nac=2010
read a_nac

echo "Ingrese su mes de nacimiento"
#let m_nac=6
read m_nac

echo "Ingrese su dia de nacimiento"
#let d_nac=1
read d_nac

echo "-----------Fecha Nacimiento---------"
echo $d_nac $m_nac $a_nac

#damos valor a las variables de la fecha actual con el método date
a_act=$(date +%Y)
m_act=$(date +%m)
d_act=$(date +%d)

echo "-----------Fecha Actual-------------"
echo $d_act $m_act $a_act

#calculamos los años desde el año de nacimiento al año actual
let edad=$a_act-$a_nac

#creamos un condición para que si el mes de nacimiento es menor que el mes actual
#quiere decir que aún no se han cumplido los años, por lo que restamos un año
#a la operación anterior que calculó los años entre las dos fechas
if [ $m_act -lt $m_nac ]; then
    #si se cumple la condición, restamos un año a la variable edad
    ((edad--))
    #Si la condición actual no se cumple, pero ...
    #los meses coinciden entré sí, nacimiento y actual, pero el día es menor
    #aunque estemos en el mismo mes, aún no ha llegado el día
    #por lo que restamos un año a la variable edad
    elif [ $m_nac -eq $m_act -a $d_act -lt $d_nac ]; then
        #restamos el año a la variable
        ((edad--))
    fi

#Finalmente damos la edad por pantalla   
echo "-----------Edad-------------------"
echo "Tienes" $edad "años"
```

CORREGIDO:

Había cometido el error en el if, al evaluar si el mes del cumpleaños era más pequeño que el mes actual, cuando es precisamente al revés, si el mes actual es más pequeño que el mes del cumpleaños, aún no se han cumplido los años, por lo que se descuenta un año.

Comment: Revisado, no se quien ha votado en negativo, pero si advertiste el error, podrías haberlo comentado por lo menos. Corregido. Había evaluado si el mes actual era menor que el mes del cumple, cuando es al revés. un saludo

Comment: Hola muchas gracias me sirvio, una pregunta mas si desearia que tenga como resultado tambien los meses y dias cumplidos que condicion se agregaria?

Comment: Hola @Ariel_PG, lamento haber tardado en contestar, pero estuve fuera unos días. Había leído tu respuesta, pero no pude ponerme con ello. Me ha llevado un montón de tiempo hacer el ejercicio a mano en Java, ahora lo estoy intentando pasar al intérprete de Bash, me llevará tiempo. Mientras, para que vayas viendo como funciona, te dejo el ejercicio en Java publicado como pregunta y respuesta. Enlace: [Solución en  Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483301/programa-para-calcular-la-edad-a-mano-sin-m%c3%a9todos-del-sistema-en-java/483302#483302)

Comment: Ok muchas gracias @el.trasgu