# Programa para calcular la edad a mano, (Sin métodos del sistema) en Java

Tags: java

Hace unos días, un usuario preguntaba como calcular la edad en el intérprete de comandos Bash de Linux

Una vez contestada la pregunta, me decía si no se podrían calcular, además de la edad en años, los meses y los días.

He realizado el ejercicio en Java, y por el poco tiempo disponible, aún no he podido adaptarlo al intérprete de comandos, estoy en ello

La pregunta venía con su código y preguntaba como completarlo, yo lo he traducido a Java y me ha parecido lo suficientemente interesante como para publicarlo en éste lenguaje

Se podría hacer con métodos y en muchas menos líneas, pero la gracia está en hacerlo sin atajos

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese su año de nacimiento");
    int a = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su mes de nacimiento");
    int m = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su dia de nacimiento");
    int d = teclado.nextInt();
            
    Date date = new Date();
    LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    int anio = localDate.getYear();
    int mes = localDate.getMonthValue();
    int dia   = localDate.getDayOfMonth();

    int day = dia - d;
    int year = anio - a;
    int month = mes - m;

    int MES = month + 12;

    if (m > mes){
        System.out.println("Tiene " + year + " años");
        System.out.println("Con " + MES + " meses");
        System.out.println("Con " + day + " dias");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Tiene " + year + " años");
        System.out.println("Con " + month + " meses");
        System.out.println("Con " + day + " dias");
    }
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo obtener la edad de una persona en años, meses y días en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376624/como-obtener-la-edad-de-una-persona-en-a%c3%b1os-meses-y-dias-en-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código resultado para el ejercicio es el siguiente

Se han separado métodos para no sobrecargar el método main, se que hay varias formas de solucinoar el problema, pero ésta es la que se me ha ocurrido a mi.

```
public class Edad {
    //declaramos las variables de enteros y las inicializamos a cero
    static int anos = 0, meses = 0, dias = 0;

    //método main
    public static void main(String[] args){   

        //creamos un array para recibir la fecha actuals llamando al método
        int[] fecha_act = metodoObtenerFechaActual();
            //almacenamos los valores del array en variables
            int a_act = fecha_act[0];
            int m_act = fecha_act[1];
            int d_act = fecha_act[2];
        
        //creamos el array que recibe la fecha del cumpleaños llamar al método y enviando el año actual por parámetro
        int[] fecha_nac = metodoPedirFecha(a_act);
            //almacenamos los valores del array en variables
            int a_nac = fecha_nac[0];
            int m_nac = fecha_nac[1];
            int d_nac = fecha_nac[2];
    
        //se imprime la fecha de nacimiento
        System.out.println("------------Fecha de Nacimiento------------");
        System.out.println(d_nac + " / " + m_nac + " / " + a_nac);

        //se imprime la fecha actual
        System.out.println("------------Fecha Actual------------------");
        System.out.println(d_act + " / " + m_act + " / " + a_act);

        //años es igual a año actual menos año nacimiento
        anos = a_act - a_nac;
        //meses año anterior = 12 (meses) menos el mes de nacimiento
        //aquí calculamos los meses que han pasado con posterioridad al cumpleaños dentro del año anterior
        int m_ano_ant = 12 - m_nac;
        //calculamos la diferencia del mes actual con el mes del cumple
        meses = m_act - m_nac;
        //en días ponemos el valor del dia de hoy
        dias = d_act;
        //creamos la variables inicializadas a cero
        int dias_aux = 0;
        int d_mes_ant = 0;

        //evaluamos que mes actual sea menor que mes de nacimiento y ...
        //que dia actual sea mayor que dia de nacimiento
        if ((m_act < m_nac) & (d_act < d_nac)) { 
            //si cumple la evaluación restamos un año
            anos--; 
            //meses igual a meses del año anterior más mes actual menos 1
            meses = (m_ano_ant + m_act) - 1; 
            //recibimos el resultado de llamar al método que calcula los días enviando fecha cumpleaños y fecha actual por parámetro
            dias_aux = metodoCalculaDias(a_nac, m_nac, d_nac, a_act, m_act, d_act);
            //el resultado anterior lo sumamos al día de hoy y lo almacenamos en la variable días
            dias = d_act + dias_aux;
            }
            //si no se cumple la anterior condición
            //evaluamos que mes actual sea mayor que mes de nacimiento y ...
            //día actual mayor que día de nacimiento
            else if ((m_act < m_nac) & (d_act > d_nac)) {
                //si se cumple, restamos un año
                anos--; 
                //sumamos meses del año anterior más meses actuales y lo almacenamos en meses
                meses = m_ano_ant + m_act;
                //calculamos días, que serán dias actuales menos día de nacimiento
                dias = d_act - d_nac;
                }
                //si mes actual mayor que mes de nacimiento y ...
                //día actual igual a día de nacimiento
                else if ((m_act < m_nac) & (d_act == d_nac)) { 
                    //restamos un año
                    anos--;
                    //meses igual a meses del año anterior más meses actuales
                    meses = m_ano_ant + m_act;  
                    //días igual a día actual menos día de nacimiento         
                    dias = d_act - d_nac;
                    }
                    //si los meses coindiden y el día actual es menor al de nacimiento
                    else if ((m_nac == m_act) & (d_act < d_nac)){ 
                        //años igual a años
                        anos = anos;
                        //meses igual a meses actuales menos mes de nacimiento
                        meses = m_act - m_nac;
                        //días igual a dia de nacimiento menos día actual
                        dias = d_nac - d_act;
                        }
                        //si coinciden los meses y el día actual es mayor que el día de nacimiento
                        else if ((m_nac == m_act) & (d_act > d_nac)){ 
                            //años igual a años
                            anos = anos;
                            //meses igual a meses actuales menos mes de nacimiento
                            meses = m_act - m_nac;
                            //días igual a día actual menos día de nacimiento
                            dias = d_act - d_nac;
                            }
                            //si coinciden meses y días
                            else if ((m_nac == m_act) & (d_act == d_nac)){ 
                                anos = anos;
                                meses = m_act - m_nac;
                                dias = d_act - d_nac;
                                System.out.println("¡¡¡ Felicidades, es tu cumple !!!");
                                }
                                //mes actual mayor que mes de nacimiento y ...
                                //día de nacimiento mayor que día actual
                                else if ((m_act > m_nac) & (d_nac > d_act)) { 
                                    anos = anos;
                                    meses--;
                                    dias_aux = metodoCalculaDias(a_nac, m_nac, d_nac, a_act, m_act, d_act);
                                    dias = d_act + dias_aux;
                                    }
                                    //mes actual mayor que mes de nacimiento y ...
                                    //día de nacimiento mayor que día actual
                                    else if ((m_act > m_nac) & (d_nac < d_act)) { 
                                        anos = anos;
                                        meses = meses;
                                        dias = d_act - d_nac;
                                        }
                                        //mes actual mayor a mes de nacimiento y ...
                                        //día de nacimiento igual a día actual
                                        else if ((m_act > m_nac) & (d_nac == d_act)) { 
                                            anos = anos;
                                            meses = meses;
                                            dias = d_act - d_nac;
                                        }
         
        //si la variable de meses del año anterior y día actual tienen valores superiores a cero
        if ((d_mes_ant > 0) & (d_act > 0)){
            //días igual a la suma de los valores de ambas variables
            dias = d_mes_ant + d_act;
        }

        //llamamos al método para imprimir los resultado y enviamos por parámetro los valores de años, meses y días
        metodoImprimirResultado(anos, meses, dias);
    }
    
    //método que calcula los días y recibe por parámetro las fechas del cumple y la actual
    public static int metodoCalculaDias(int a_nac, int m_nac, int d_nac, int a_act, int m_act, int d_act){
    
        //variable para almacenar los días del mes anterior
        int d_mes_ant = 0;
    
        //variables para los meses
        int ene = 1;
        int feb = 2;
        int mar = 3;
        int abr = 4;
        int may = 5;
        int jun = 6;
        int jul = 7;
        int ago = 8;
        int sep = 9;
        int oct = 10;
        int nov = 11;
        int dic = 12;

        //-----------variables para los años bisiestos-------------
        int b_24 = 2024;
        int b_28 = 2028;
        int b_32 = 2032;
        int b_36 = 2036;
        int b_40 = 2040;
    
        //si el mes actual es un més de 31 días salvo marzo
        if ((m_act == ene) || (m_act == may) || (m_act == jul) || (m_act == ago) || (m_act == oct) || (m_act == dic)) {
            //restamos a 30 días que tendrá el mes anterior los días de la fecha de nacimiento
            d_mes_ant = 30 - d_nac;
            }
            //si el mes actual es un més de 30 días
            else if ((m_act == abr) || (m_act == jun) || (m_act == sep) || (m_act == nov)){
                //el mes anterior será de 31 días, y restamos a esos días los días de la fecha de nacimiento
                d_mes_ant = 31 - d_nac;
                }
                //si el mes actual es marzo y el año es bisiesto
                else if ((m_act == mar) & ((a_act == b_24) || (a_act == b_28) || (a_act == b_32) || (a_act == b_36) || (a_act == b_40))){
                    //restamos los días de la fecha de nacimiento a 29 días
                    d_mes_ant = 29 - d_nac;
                    }
                    //si no es año bisiesto y es el mes de marzo
                    else if (m_act == mar){
                        //rstamos los días de nacimiento a 28 días
                        d_mes_ant = 28 - d_nac;
                    }
        //retornamos el array del resultado
        return d_mes_ant;
    }

    //método que pide la fecha de nacimiento
    public static int[] metodoPedirFecha(int a_act){

        //instanciamos la clase escaner
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //creamos un array para almacenar las fechas
        int[] fecha_nac = new int[3];
    
        //creamos tres bucles do while para que itere mientras no reciba el dato adecuado para los años, los meses y los días respectivamente y almacena el resultado en el array
        do{        
            System.out.println("Ingrese su año de nacimiento: ");
            fecha_nac[0] = teclado.nextInt(); 
    
            if ((fecha_nac[0] < 1900) & (fecha_nac[0] > a_act)){
                System.out.println("El año introducido " + fecha_nac[0] + " no es válido");
            }   
         //que itere mientras el dato dado por teclado no sea un número entre 1900 y el año actual     
        }while ((fecha_nac[0] < 1900) & (fecha_nac[0] > a_act));
    
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su mes de nacimiento: ");
            fecha_nac[1] = teclado.nextInt(); 
    
            if ((fecha_nac[1] < 1) & (fecha_nac[1] > 12)){
                System.out.println("Recuerde que el año tiene 12 meses y " + fecha_nac[1] + " no es un mes válido");
            }        
         //que itere mientras el dato dado por teclado no sea un número entre 1 y 12
        }while ((fecha_nac[1] < 1) & (fecha_nac[1] > 12));
    
        do{
            System.out.println("ingrese su día de nacimiento: ");
            fecha_nac[2] = teclado.nextInt(); 
    
            if ((fecha_nac[0] < 1) & (fecha_nac[0] > 31)){
                System.out.println("Un mes tiene un máximo de 31 días, " + fecha_nac[2] + " no es un día válido");
            } 
        //que itere mientras el dato dado por teclado no sea un número entre 1 y 31      
        }while ((fecha_nac[0] < 1) & (fecha_nac[0] > 31));
    
        //retornamos el array
        return fecha_nac;
    }

    //método que obtiene la fecha actual y devuelve un array con los datos de la misma
    public static int[] metodoObtenerFechaActual(){

        //declaramos el array con los datos
        int[] fecha_act = new int[3];

        //creamos un objeto date de la clase Date
        Date date = new Date();

        //obtenemos los datos y los almacenamos en el array
        LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        fecha_act[0] = localDate.getYear();
        fecha_act[1] = localDate.getMonthValue();
        fecha_act[2] = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
    
        //retornamos el array
        return fecha_act;
    }

    //método que imprime los resultado que recibe por parámetro
    private static void metodoImprimirResultado(int anos, int meses, int dias) {

        System.out.println("---------------Edad-----------------------");

        //condicionantes para formatear la salida en función de los resultados
        //si es un año, cero meses y algún día ó ...
        //es un año, algún més y cero días
        if (((anos == 1) & (meses == 0) & (dias != 0)) || 
            ((anos == 1) & (meses != 0) & (dias == 0))){
            System.out.print("Tienes " + anos + " años, y ");
            }
            //si es un año
            else if (anos == 1){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Tienes " + anos + " año, ");
                }
                //si no es cero y tampoco 1 y meses y días son cero
                else if ((anos != 0) & (anos != 1) & (meses == 0) & (dias == 0)){
                    System.out.print("Tienes " + anos + " años");
                    }
                    //si no es cero, no es uno, meses es cero y días diferente de cero
                    else if ((anos != 0) & (anos != 1) & (meses == 0) & (dias != 0)){
                        System.out.print("Tienes " + anos + " años y ");
                        }
                        //años diferente de cero y de uno
                        else if ((anos != 0) & (anos != 1)){
                            System.out.print("Tienes " + anos + " años, ");
                            }
                            //años sea cero
                            else if (anos == 0){
                                System.out.print("Tienes ");
                            }
               
        //meses 1 y días 0
        if ((meses == 1) & (dias == 0)){
            System.out.print(meses + " mes");
            }
            //meses 1 y días distinto a cero
            else if ((meses == 1) & (dias != 0)){
                System.out.print(meses + " mes y ");
                }
                //meses igual a cero
                else if (meses == 0){
                    System.out.print("");
                    }
                    //meses distinto a cero y uno y días igual a cero
                    else if ((meses != 0) & (meses != 1) & (dias == 0)){
                        System.out.print(meses + " meses");
                        }
                        //meses distinto a cero y uno
                        else if ((meses != 0) & (meses != 1)){
                            System.out.print(meses + " meses y ");
                        }

        //si días igual a uno
        if (dias == 1){
            System.out.print(dias + " dia");
            }
            //si dias igual a cero
            else if (dias == 0){
                System.out.print("");
                }
                //si días distinto a cero y uno
                else if ((dias != 0) & (dias != 1)){
                    System.out.print(dias + " dias");
                }
        //dos líneas en blanco
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Completito, me lo copio